# How to automatically scroll to bottom, and scroll to top if at bottom

Tags: javascript, php, html, scroll

For a project I need to scroll every 7 seconds a bit further down the page, and if it reaches the bottom, it scrolls back up. And that over and over.

I've made it so far that it scrolls down every 7 seconds. I tried like 20 options to scroll to the top if it touches the bottom, but none of them worked.

My code:

```
<head><link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="vendor/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="roostersb.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
.klok{
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  right: 18%;
  top: 7%;
}

h2.klok{
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  right: 2%;
  text-transform: capitalize; 
  top: 0,5%;
}

.timer{
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  position: fixed;
  color: black;
}


.tr{
  font-size: 150%;
}

h1.kaaart{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 11%;
  right: 2%;
}


.kaaart{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 10px;*/
  /*-moz-border-radius: 10px;*/
  /*border-radius: 10px;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 17px #414243;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 17px #414243;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 17px #414243;
    text-align: center;
    /*horizontal-align: middle;*/
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


.mijntafel{
  font-size: 160%;
}

.mijntafeltop{
  font-size: 180%;
}

th.mijntafeltop{
  font-size: 170%;
}

.corvee{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
}

h4.corvee{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.afwezig{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
}

h4.afwezig{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ziek{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
}

h4.ziek{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.extra{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
}

h4.extra{
  font: italic bold;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h4.mededeling{
  font: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #333333;
}

.mededeling{
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #333333;
}

</style>
</head>
<script>
/*window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        (function smoothscroll(){
    var currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (currentScroll > 0) {
         window.requestAnimationFrame(smoothscroll);
         window.scrollTo (0,currentScroll - (currentScroll/5));
    }
})();
    }
};*/

/*window.onscroll = function() {
  var d = document.documentElement;
  var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
  var height = d.offsetHeight;

  console.log('offset = ' + offset);
  console.log('height = ' + height);

  if (offset === height) {
       alert("At the bottom")
  }
};*/


window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("you're at the bottom of the page");
    }
};


function countdown() {
    var count = 8;
    var timerId = setInterval(
        function() {
        count--;
        console.log(count);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
        if(count == 0) {
            count = 8;
        window.scrollBy(0, 685);        
        }
        if(count == 1) {


        }
        if(count == 2) {


        }
    }, 1000);
}


countdown();
</script>


<body onload="doRedirect(); show5(); pie();" cz-shortcut-listen="true">

<?php
$datum = date("d-m-Y");

$url = 'http://rooster.kajmunk.nl/wijzigingen/18-12-2017';

$urlmed = 'http://rooster.kajmunk.nl/mededelingen/18-12-2017';

$urlhtml = file_get_contents($url);

$urlhtmlmooi = strstr($urlhtml, '<table');

$urlhtmlmooi1 = str_replace('<thead><tr><th width="15%">Klas</th><th width="20%">Uur</th><th width="33%">Nieuwe situatie</th><th width="33%">Oude situatie</th></tr></thead>','',$urlhtmlmooi);

$urlhtmlmooi2 = str_replace('<tr class="','<tr class="tr ',$urlhtmlmooi1);

$urlhtmlsupermooi = str_replace("roosterwijzigingen","centered striped mijntafel",$urlhtmlmooi2);


$urlmedhtml = file_get_contents($urlmed);

$urlmedhtmlmooi = strstr($urlmedhtml, '<div class="content"'); 

$urlmedhtmlsupermooi1 = str_replace(' class="content"',"",$urlmedhtmlmooi);

$urlmedhtmlsupermooi2 = str_replace('<h1>','<h1 class="extra">',$urlmedhtmlsupermooi1);

//$urlmedhtmlsupermooi2 = str_replace(' class="mededeling"',"",$urlmedhtmlsupermooi1);

$urlmedhtmlsupermooi = str_replace('h1','h4',$urlmedhtmlsupermooi2);

//$tussendoor1 = str_replace(' class="ziek"',"",$urlmedhtmlmooi1);

//$tussendoor2 = str_replace(' class="corvee"',"",$tussendoor1);

//$urlmedhtmlsupermooi = str_replace(' class="afwezig"',"",$tussendoor2);



?>
  <h2 id="timer" class="timer">timer...</h2>
    <div style="width:74%; position:fixed; float: left"><table class="mijntafeltop white centered striped"><thead><tr class="mijntafeltop"><th width="15%">Klas</th><th width="20%">Uur</th><th width="33%">Nieuwe situatie</th><th width="33%">Oude situatie</th></tr></thead></table></div>
    <div style="width:74%; top: 1%; float: left"><?php echo $urlhtmlsupermooi;?></div>
    <div class="card-panel teal darken kaaart klok" style="width:24%; height:16%; right: 1%; top: 2%; position:fixed;"></div>

<script src="js/liveclock.js" language="JavaScript">
</script>




<div class="klok" id="liveclock"><i class="large material-icons">school</i><h2>Uur kapot<br>Klok kapot</h2></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="spacing"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content" class="">
<script>var duration = 0;</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
duration = 7000
var sTargetURL = ""
  function doRedirect() {
   setTimeout( "timedRedirect()", 7000 );
  }
  function timedRedirect() {
  }
  $('body').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    } 

    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    }
  });

</script>
</div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var timer;
      var timerCurrent;
      var timerFinish;
      var timerSeconds;

      function drawTimer(percent)
      {
        var html = '<div id="slice"'+(percent > 50?' class="gt50"':'')
             + '><div class="pie"></div>' + ( percent > 50 ?'<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>';
        $('div.timer').html(html);
        var deg = 360/100*percent;
        $('#slice .pie').css({
          '-moz-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
          '-o-transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)',
          'transform':'rotate('+deg+'deg)'
        }); 
      }

      function stopWatch()
      {
        var seconds = (timerFinish-(new Date().getTime()))/1000;
        if (seconds <= 0)
        {
          drawTimer(100);
          clearInterval(timer);
          $('input[type=button]#watch').val('Start');
          /* alert('Finished counting down from '+timerSeconds); */
        } else {
          var percent = 100-((seconds/timerSeconds)*100);
          drawTimer(percent);
        }
      }

      function pie()
      {
        console.log(duration);
        timerSeconds = duration/1000;
        timerCurrent = 0;
        timerFinish = new Date().getTime()+(timerSeconds*1000);
        timer = setInterval('stopWatch()',50);
      };

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post( "http://localhost", { timestamp : $.now() });
      });
    </script></div>
    <div class="card-panel white kaaart" style="width:24%; height:65%; right: 1%; top: 20%; position:fixed;"><?php echo $urlmedhtmlsupermooi; ?></div>



</body>
<button id="button" style="display: none;" onclick="scrollWin()">Scroll down</button>
```

With its now like: https://sj3rd.nl/schermen.php

Comment: could you please add the function that scrolls the page to your post?

Comment: My post? I dont get it

Comment: sorry, bad grammar :) please edit your question and add the function to it (the whole code is too confusing for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
function countdown() {
var count = 8;
var timerId = setInterval(
    function() {
    count--;
    console.log(count);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
    if(count == 0) {
        count = 8;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
        else {
            window.scrollBy(0, 685);
        }


    }
    if(count == 1) {


    }
    if(count == 2) {


    }
}, 1000);
}
```